# Dishwasher and garbage disposal wiring in same gang box

Tags: electrical, dishwasher, nec, garbage-disposal

I am in the planning stages of renovating my kitchen.  I plan on wiring my garbage disposal under the sink and using one of those air switches to control it.  The wiring is not a problem.  However, to prevent excessive clutter I planned on pulling the circuit for the dishwasher into the same gang box I will mount under my sink.  I am not using the same circuit - each is wired independently.  But I just don't want the dishwasher line coming in through the back of the sink cabinet straight to the dishwasher, I would like to have some clean wiring down there.

So I planned on pulling the DW circuit into the same box where I am putting an outlet for the disposal.

Any issues with that, other than the standard calculations for box size?

Comment: This is a very common way to do it. I'll let somebody more familiar with code answer, though.

Comment: I take it the DW and GD are on separate circuits?

Comment: Will they be on GFCI breakers?

Comment: Would the dishwasher be plugged into the receptacle (under the sink) and if so would the power cord pass through a hole in the wall between the cabinets?

Comment: If using a receptacle for DW and you are subject to 2020 NEC receptacles in the cabinet under the sink are required to be GFCI protected, so you may need a double box to install separate receptacles GFCI receptacles being fed by AFCI breakers. Even if dual function breakers are available separate receptacles would likely be needed to avoid common trip requirement if on the same yoke. (If still subject to the 2017 NEC the definition of doorway can be argued to not require GFCI protection.)

Comment: Yes, DW and GD are on different circuits.

Comment: I'm not sure if I would use a receptacle for the DW - I'm fine just having it wired within the gang box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is up to code even today with GFCI protection. I would locate the receptacles on the sink side so the dishwasher can be plugged in there through a hole in the cabinet as Jim Stewart commented and this would pass inspection unless there are some local code restrictions above and beyond the NEC. You could do it with a deep single gang and break the tabs on both the hot and neutral if the GFCI’s are in your panel.

Comment: Just a clarification, NEC 422.16 requires DW receptacles be in a cabinet adjacent to the DW, and if you don't use a receptacle a local switch or permanent breaker lock-out is required.

Comment: That is what is being suggested here.